# Amazon Cloudfront Node detection

Tags: detection

I have been using Amazon Cloudfront to server up media/js/css files stored in Amazon S3 for a website that is accessed internationally. I want to find out if Cloudfront is using the nearest node from the point of origin of the web page request. So for example is someone from Hong Kong is requesting my website's home page, the static files like media/js/css are getting served up from the node in Singapore.

How can I figure this out other than renting server space on EC2 in Hong Kong and pinging the resource from there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can measure the total load time (including image elements) for visitors with Google Analytics as detailed in the [Measure Page Load Time with Site Speed Analytics Report](http://analytics.blogspot.com/2011/05/measure-page-load-time-with-site-speed.html) analytics blog post.

It would also be possible to roll your own solution by authoring a Javascript which, when run by a client, checks load time against a resource pulled from Cloudfront and reports the time taken back to your server (though doing so is unnecessary if implementing Google Analytics).